# Pact JVM, get array without any root as response

Tags: java, pact, pact-jvm

Using Pack for JVM using Junit5. Maven dependency that I have used is as follows.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to create DslPart response pattern based below JSON payload.

```
[
   "Africa/Abidjan",
   "Asia/Tokyo",
   "Africa/Addis_Ababa",
   ...
]
```

I managed to define the below DslPart definition, which makes the test pass.

```
   DslPart expectedZoneResponse = new PactDslJsonArray()
            .stringValue("Africa/Abidjan")
            .stringValue("Asia/Tokyo");
```

Pact definition is.

```
@Pact(consumer = "Client", provider = "ServiceApi")
public RequestResponsePact getTestArray(PactDslWithProvider builder)
    return builder
           .given("ZoneInfo")
            .uponReceiving("Return all zones.")
              .path("/zones")
              .method("GET")
            .willRespondWith()
              .status(200)
              .body(expectedZoneResponse)
            .toPact();
```

The above Client test creates the pact definition file but when I run it against my provider contract test, it fails because the response got from server is way more then the static 2 string defined in the pact definition file.

```
body: $ Expected a List with 2 elements but received 603 elements
```

My intent was to provide string pattern "[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+" in **DslPart expectedZoneResponse**, which could be matched, but I could not achieve it.

How can I modify **DslPart expectedZoneResponse** so that I reflects a patten instead of the 2 string constant?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrayEachLike` or `arrayMinLike`/`arrayMaxLike` like this:

```java
DslPart expectedZoneResponse = 
  PactDslJsonArray.arrayEachLike()
    .stringValue("Africa/Abidjan")
    .stringValue("Asia/Tokyo");
```

See also https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/consumer#matching-json-values-at-the-root